# finding two positive integers in an array

Tags: functions, logic

I'm facing a problem these days, the question is saying the following:
" Imagine we are having an array of positive integers called (a) and a variable called (k). Among this integers, we are looking for two numbers such that the sum of these two would be the (k). we are in need of designing such algorithm with complexity O(n) that prints out the locations of this two number(if exist)."

for example:
**a[6,3,2, 1, 8]  ----- n=5 ----- k=8 ------ numbers: 6,2**

in this case what would be the designing of the algorithm?

Thank you all for your efforts, they worth a lot!

Comment: Are you sure that such an algorithm exists?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $k$ can be at least considered to be $O\left(n\right)$, but ideally that $k \ll n$, i.e., $k$ is much smaller than $n$, and there is sufficient memory available, here is a relatively simple method. Have a "list" (note I am calling this as a mathematical name, not necessarily as a computer construct, as things like single-linked lists have individual access times of $O\left(k^2\right)$ (so it'll require that $k \ll n$), but I am assuming will use a contiguous array, so each element can be accessed directly, making individual access times be a small constant), call it $L$, of $\left\lfloor \frac{k}{2} \right\rfloor$ ordered arrays of $2$ positive integers which add to $k$, i.e., $\left(1, k - 1\right), \left(2, k - 2\right), \ldots, \left(\left\lfloor \frac{k}{2} \right\rfloor, \left\lfloor \frac{k + 1}{2} \right\rfloor\right)$. For example, for $k = 3$, we have just $\left(1, 2\right)$ while for $k = 3$, we have $\left(1, 3\right), \left(2, 2\right)$. Next, have some sort of structure attached to each value to keep track of which, if any, element of the main array has been found for it, with special attention paid to the case where $k$ is even due to the repeated value of the last element in $L$, i.e., $\left(\frac{k}{2}, \frac{k}{2}\right)$.

Now, go through each element of the main array. If it is $\lt k$, check the appropriate element in $L$ to see whether or not it already has something associated with it. If so, ignore it. Otherwise, assign the value in $L$ to this main array element. If the other element in the array in $L$ already has something assigned to it also, then you are done. Note that this finds the first set of elements which add to $k$, but there may be other ones. Otherwise, if you finish checking the main array with no array in $L$ matching, then there is no such result. In either case, this is altogether an $O\left(n\right)$ algorithm, with a certain fixed amount for the initial set up of $L$, and a fairly small maximum # of steps for checking each element of the main array. Note the constant to use in the $O\left(n\right)$ function depends a fair bit on how large your $k$ can be in relation to $n$. Also, if there is no particular limit on $k$, especially if you can't have any assurance you can fit the list $L$ into memory, then I believe that both [TonyK](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1508/tonyk) and [Penguino](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/90137/penguino) are likely correct, i.e., there is no such algorithm.

Note I don't know what language you are using, so I didn't try to write it in program code. Also, it's been over $35$ years since I wrote any psuedocode, so I didn't want to try to do that either. However, I trust my explanation is sufficient enough for you to understand my method.

Comment: Interesting idea - O(n) but also O(k^2), so 'results may vary'.

Comment: @Penguino Thanks for the feedback. I have now clarified that when I said that $L$ is a "list", I meant as a mathematical construct, not necessarily a computer one. If it's implemented as a contiguous array (which I believe it should usually be, and all computing languages I know of support this), then it's individual access times are a constant. As such, if $k$ is of $O\left(n\right)$, then the overall implementation time will still be of $O\left(n\right)$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan  I'm confident that you are correct, that no such algorithm exists. My "answer" is merely a quip on the problem, and incidentally it is of $O(n^2)$.

Comment: @C.Melton With no limitation on $k$, we are in agreement there is likely no such algorithm. However, if can limit $k$ to be $O\left(n\right)$, then my algorithm, if it can be implemented in available memory, is $O\left(n\right)$. Perhaps this is the intention of the OP, but nothing about any limitation of $k$ is stated explicitly in the question text, so we can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this in Python; it might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it could help with the idea:

```
from random import randint
n=int(input("Input the size of your array (n>1): "))
print("You chose",n)
k=int(input("Input the value of k (k>1): "))
print("You chose",k)
a=[]
for i in range(0, n):  
    a.append(randint(1,101))
print() 
print(a)
counter=0
for i in range(0, n):
    j=i
    while j < n:
        if a[i]+a[j]==k:
            print(a[i], "+", a[j], "=", k)
            print(a[i], "is in position", i,".  ", a[j], "is in position", j)
            counter=1
        j=j+1
if counter==0:
    print("There do not exist such two numbers adding to k =", k)
```

Snippet:
[image: Sample Code]

Comment: But this is $O(n^2)$, I think.

Comment: I realize it's only meant to be sample code, but where does the "101" come from in your line "a.append(randint(1,101))"? Should it not be some maximum value, such as a maximum positive integer, or even better yet, perhaps $k$? Otherwise, if $k \gt 202$, it's guaranteed that no solution will be found.

Comment: The number 101 came off the top of my head.  I had to enter something, otherwise the random number generator would not have a range to work with.  In theory, the values of the elements of the array could be arbitrarily large, not dependent on the value of k.  There is no condition that a solution must exist, just that if it does, it should be printed with its position in the array.

Comment: Why a screenshot of code?!

Comment: @C.Melton It's not just for me. The problem with images of text, besides aesthetics, is that they lose the presented data (for example, the text contained in an image is not conveniently useable or searchable). Note that these message boards do support preformatted text like code (and code output): see [markdown editing help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help). Good luck!

Comment: @RichardAmbler  Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, I don't think that it is possible to perform this search in $O(n)$. However, it *is* possible to build up a data structure in $O(n^2)$ and then query the data structure in constant time. This wouldn't be very useful if you are working with a new list of numbers each time, but would greatly improve efficiency if you were performing multiple queries on the same list of numbers.

In the following example I'm going to append 5 to your list (since it may be the case that there is more than one pair of numbers that sum to a given $k$). Also, I've used the [*trotter* library](https://pypi.org/project/trotter/) (shameless plug), which just provides a convenient way to arrange the potential pairs in the list during the set up stage in this example.

```
import trotter as tr

def sum_mapper(ns):
    sm = dict()
    for combo in tr.Combinations(2, ns): 
        s = sum(combo)
        if s not in sm:
            sm[s] = []
        sm[s].append(combo)
    return sm

def query(sm, k):
    if k not in sm:
        return []
    return sm[k]

ns = [6, 3, 2, 1, 8, 5]

# The set up is not in O(n)...
ns_map = sum_mapper(ns)

# ... but querying pairs that sum to k is in constant time.
while(True):
    k = int(input("Query: "))
    print(query(ns_map, k))
```

Sample output:

```
Query: 8
[[6, 2], [3, 5]]
Query: 11
[[6, 5], [3, 8]]
Query: 5
[[3, 2]]
Query: 2
[]
Query:
```

Answer (score -1):

A naive solution would be to test each element i with each element j until the sum is achieved. That will be an O(*n*^2) algorithm

```
for i = 1 to n-1 do   
  for j = 2 to n do
    if A[i]+A[j]=k then return (i,j) and halt 
return "no solution"
```

A better solution would be to sort the array first then check for your equality. That will be O(*n*log*n*)

```
sort A
i=1
j=n
while (i < j) and (A[i]+A[j] < k) do inc(i) 
while (i < j) and (A[i]+A[j] > k) do dec(j)
if (i <> j) return (i,j) and halt else return "no solution"
```

I doubt that an O(n) solution exists for unsorted data. If the data is already sorted then the second algorithm, minus the first line, is O(*n*).

Comment: Your algorithm fails on e.g. $a=\{1,2,3,100\}$ and $k=5$. After the first `while` loop, `i` is still $1$; and the second `while` loop can do nothing to change that. I think you need to iterate those two `while` loops, which will still be $O(n)$. (Also, it should be `if (i <> j and A[i]+A[j]==k) return (i,j)...`)

Comment: Yes, I am sure you are correct. The 'algorithm' was more a placeholder to describe a procedure where you 'erode' from the top and bottom of a  pre-sorted list to find a suitable pair in O(n). Not an exact or provably correct version of it.

Comment: If you knew it wouldn't work, why did you post it?

Comment: I didn't 'know it wouldn't work'. I just didn't debug it fully.